# Print active users count from the windowed kafka stream to the console

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to aggregate the stream to get the count of user_id's within the windowed stream.
Stream doesn't have key ,so need to get the user_id from the value and aggregate and print the count of active users within that window to the console/api.
Here's the code:

```
        final KStream<String, avroschema> feeds = builder.stream("input_topic");
final KTable<String, Long> aggregated = feeds
            // map the user id as key
            .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getUserId().toString(), value))
            .groupByKey()
            .count("state_store");
aggregated.print();
```

output i am getting  is :

```
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000002]: 123 , (1<-null)
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000002]: 456 , (1<-null)
[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000002]: 789 , (1<-null)
```

How can I print only the count in the output like below?

```
 user_count 3
```

I tried to get the count as below:

```
   KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> countUsers = feeds
            // map the user name as key, because the subsequent counting is performed based on the key
            .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.getUserId().toString(), value))
            // count users, using one-minute tumbling windows
            .countByKey(TimeWindows.of("UserCountWindow", 60 * 1000L))
```

but it is showing error as below.What's wrong with that?

```
Cannot resolve method 'countByKey(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows)'
```

Comment: Do you store users activity in Kafka? Why not in Redis store then pull data into Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

I you set the user-id as key, you count how often each user appears. This count is obviously `1`.

If you want to count all users, you need to set a "dummy key" that is the same for all records you want to count.

For the compilation error: it's just wrong code. Read the docs: https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#id12

Not sure what version you are using but `.countByKey(TimeWindows.of("UserCountWindow", 60 * 1000L))` is old API that was changed in 0.11 release.